# Create an automatic FUNCTION (fx) to pull the data from INPUT tab in respective columns

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, match

I need to pick data from sheet1(input sheet) and populate it to sheet2, but while running index + match issue that I have facing is that my input sheet have region and market in same column but where as the sheet 2 have them in different column. actually I need to run the row_num multiple times.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9H6XK.png) This is the reference of input sheet
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhB0v.png) This is the sheet that I need to populate.

I have used formula "=INDEX(Input!$I$6:$I$64,MATCH($B11,Input!$A$5:$A$64,0),MATCH(TRIM($C$8),Input!$B$6:$B$64,0))"  and its working for the 1st category "Overall budget" but not working for others. Please help or suggest a better way to achieve this.